# Ruby equivalent to Ipython %timeit

Tags: ruby, timing

#### tl;dr; How can I time how long something takes in Ruby?

Ipython's `%timeit` and `%%timeit` are two of my most frequently used IPython Magic commands (A Python Interactive shell) . 
Generically `%timeit` is not that different from a function like this:

```
def timeit(f, *args, **kwargs): 
  num_trials = estimate_number_of_trials_for_f(f, args, kwargs) 
  start = time.time() 
  for i in range(num_trials): 
    f(args, kwargs) 
  return time.time() - start
```

The advantage is that interactively it's possible to do something like this (not a great example use case I know):

```
In [119]: %%timeit
   .....: data = json.loads(json_data)
   .....: ret =  process_data(data) 
   .....: json.dumps(ret)
```

I was wondering if there was a ruby (irb or pry) equivalent to them, or an idiomatic way to implement the equivalent in general (a timeit which accepts only a single method is not quite the same, it would be good to get the equivalent of the %timeit magic for any arbitrary block of code as in the later example).

Comment: You might get help from more Rubyists if you explain what `%timeit` and `%%timeit` are.

Comment: @sevenseacat thanks, I updated.

Comment: You can run ruby code in Ipython using `%%ruby`

Comment: If whoever is downvoting wants to post a comment to explain why that would be great, thanks.

Comment: @user3467349 I didn't downvote but my guess would be someone downvoted you because (even after your edit) it's not clear what python functionality you're attempting to replicate. The first sentence of Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) clearly and succinctly describes it as "a simple way to time small bits of Python code" which would have been helpful to include in your question. There is a gem named [timeit](https://rubygems.org/gems/timeit/versions/0.0.4) you may want to checkout for replicating this functionality in ruby.

Comment: Sometime it's simpler to just update the question.  Done.

Answer (score 4):

Benchmark -
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-benchmark
can help you with this.

Example:

```
require "benchmark"

how_long = Benchmark.measure do
  (1..100).each { |i| i }
end
puts how_long
```

Comment: The `benchmark-ips` gem is likely a better alternative since OP's code contains `estimate_number_of_trials_for_f`. From its [README.md](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips/blob/master/README.md): _One benefit to using this method is benchmark-ips automatically determines the data points for testing our code, so we can focus on the results instead of guessing iteration counts as we do with the traditional Benchmark library._

Comment: That seems like the samething as `start = Time.now; #do stuff; puts "#{start - Time.now}"` ? Since it's not estimating the number of loops required.